# WPF Detailsview 

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the best solution to have something like a web_application DetaisView control(horizontal dataGrid with just one row!) with binding, insert and update features?

[image]

- using horizontal datagrid
- using a special listview
- ...

Comment: And what does your edit mean, "without using a specific component?"  Which component do you not want to use?

Comment: @DanPuzey sorry, I mean without using *any* components!

Comment: @ARZ: And i want to write programs without *any* code!

Comment: What about WPF DetailsView control? It is similar to DetailsView in WebForms http://wpfdetailsview.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user control that contains the specified fields you need to edit an item of your list

```
<UserControl x:Class="DisplayUserControl" ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Bind the user control datacontext to the selected item of your List

```
<MainWindow>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding to your data}" x:Name="list"/>
    <local:DisplayUserControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list}"/>
</MainWindow>
```

I just used a simple ListBox for displaying data